# dynamically filter params values for logging

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

to capture some errors I would like to through the query string parameters into a log file to help diagnose.

```
$mylog.info "bad information " + parms.to_json.to_s
```

However sometimes there is sensitive information, such as a password. I know there is 'filter_parameter_logging' that can be set however doing something like this doesn't work.

```
params['filter_parameter_logging'] = :password
```

How would I go about dynamically masking some of the values?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your class Application

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```